# Launching the gallery from an specific href? (lightgallery)

Tags: jquery, lightgallery

I have list of images and i display only 3, but on third one i want to call lightgallery that will display all images. Any suggestion how can i do that?

```
<div id="sync2" class="owl-carousel">
                    @foreach($property_gallery as $key=>$property_image)
                    <div class="data-src="/storage/uploads/{{$property_image->path }}">
                      @if($key == 2)
                      <a class='firstImage' href="/storage/uploads/{{$property_image->path }}">
                        <div class="see_all_gallery">
                          <h4>SEE ALL {{ count($property_gallery) }} PHOTOS</h4>
                          <span>VIEW GALLERY <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                        </div>
                      @else
                      <a href="/storage/uploads/{{$property_image->path }}" onclick="javascript:doSomething();">
                      @endif

                      <img src="/storage/uploads/{{$property_image->path }}" alt="" />
                      </a>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                  </div>
```